# MsAccess: Calculating a field in a table with one from a Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query with a calculated column and a table with a field named totals. I want to produce a column in the table RDaccounts that subtracts the 'totals' from the figures in the query with identical RDcodes. How best can I do this?

I wanted to post some images but unfortunately I cant because i don't have enough reputations.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Well, you are going to have to give us some more information if you want any help.  Can you provide the query?  Also, give us the table structure.  Then we could probably help you combine everything into one query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any examples or even code for us to work with, but if I'm reading you right, try this:

1. Make a new query.
2. For your sources, use your first query and your table.
3. Join your first query and the table by the RDcode.
4. Subtract away.